# Fetching from SQL and displaying on frontend errors

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs

I am working on a workout website for practice and fun. I can enter a workout and it saves to mysql but when i try and fetch and show the workouts in the db im getting errors. In Postman i can see users but using http://localhost:3000/api/workouts Just shows a blank page.

http://localhost:3000/test-db This on the other hand works. I will attach my code, i cant see why
http://localhost:3000/api/workouts doesnt show workouts.

SELECT * FROM workouts in mysql does show the workouts.

It has to be something with my server.js, I want to be able to see the workouts on postman.

I cannot post images due to not having 10 rep.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const db = require('./src/config/db'); // Adjust the path as needed to your db config
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
// app.use(cors());
app.use(cors({
  origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:3001'], // allow requests from these origins
  methods: ['GET', 'POST'], // allow these HTTP methods
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'], // allow these headers
}));

// Test endpoint to check database connection
app.get('/test-db', (req, res) => {
    // Query the database to retrieve a list of tables
    db.query('SHOW TABLES', (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send('Database connection error');
      } else {
        // Return the list of tables as JSON response
        res.status(200).json(results);
      }
    });
});

// Login endpoint for user authentication
app.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  
  // Query database for user by email and password
  const query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?';
  db.query(query, [email, password], (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ message: "Database error", error: err });
    }
    if (results.length === 0) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid email or password" });
    }
    
    // Send success response if user is found
    res.json({ message: "Login successful" });
  });
});

// Signup endpoint for user registration
app.post('/api/signup', async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    // Check if user already exists in the database
    const existingUser = await db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email]);
    if (existingUser.length > 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Email already exists' });
    }

    // Insert new user into the database
    await db.query('INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (?, ?)', [email, password]);

    // Return success message if user is successfully registered
    res.status(201).json({ message: 'User registered successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'An error occurred. Please try again later.' });
  }
});

// Endpoint to save workout data to the database
app.post('/api/workouts', async (req, res) => {
  const { workout } = req.body;

  try {
    // Insert the workout data into the database without the workout_date field
    await db.query('INSERT INTO workouts (workout_name, user_id) VALUES (?, ?)', [workout.workout_name, workout.user_id]);

    // Return success message if workout is successfully saved
    res.status(201).json({ message: 'Workout saved successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'An error occurred. Please try again later.' });
  }
});


// Endpoint to fetch all workouts from the database
app.get('/api/workouts', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    
    const workouts = await db.query('SELECT * FROM workouts');

    console.log('Workouts:', workouts); 

    const workoutRows = workouts.rows;
  
    res.status(200).json(workoutRows);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching workouts:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'An error occurred. Please try again later.' });
  }
});




const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

I have tried changing the server.js code but nothing seems to work.

Comment: "*im getting errors*"- Please provide the full error inside the question - [ask]

Comment: FYI: You should not store passwords as plaintext

Comment: @DarkBee yeah i am just doing this for fun and had plans to store the passwords a more secure way. I just wanted to see if i can get the data to display first.

Comment: @DarkBee The error is a white screen on postman with no words explaining why

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.